# Splitting a Python data frame string and saving the last split part into new column

Tags: python, dataframe, split

I would like to split the strings of a specific column of a dataframe by " - " and save the last part into a new column. This works outside a df:

```
s0 = '34 years old woman with pain in her XXX - Pharyngitis'
s1 = '67 years old man with xxx - yyy zzz - Nephropathy'
s2 = 'Metastatic Liver Cancer'

print(s0.split(" - ")[-1])  # works
print(s1.split(" - ")[-1])
print(s2.split(" - ")[-1])
```

But not with a data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([s0, s1, s2], columns=['title'])
df['diagnosis'] = df['title'].str.split(' - ')[-1]  # KeyError: -1
print(df['diagnosis'])
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure negative index works on dataframe. df.str.split() returns a dataframe, so you have to merge your first dataframe with the new one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of splitting a string into a list of chunks - [`pd.Series.str.rfind`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.rfind.html) is a way to go:

```
In [104]: df['title'].apply(lambda s: s[s.rfind('-') + 1:].strip())                                         
Out[104]: 
0                Pharyngitis
1                Nephropathy
2    Metastatic Liver Cancer
Name: title, dtype: object
```

Comment: The white space before and after the "-" is missing (as it stands it fails on a diagnosis that contains a - somewhere) otherwise I guess this is the most runtime efficient solution ...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `apply` and `lambda` here:

```py
s0 = '34 years old woman with pain in her XXX - Pharyngitis'
s1 = '67 years old man with xxx - yyy zzz - Nephropathy'
s2 = 'Metastatic Liver Cancer'

df = pd.DataFrame([s0, s1, s2], columns=['title'])

df['diagnosis'] = df['title'].apply(lambda x: x.split(' - ')[-1]) 

print(df['diagnosis'])
```

Prints:

```
0                Pharyngitis
1                Nephropathy
2    Metastatic Liver Cancer
Name: diagnosis, dtype: object
```

If you like an empty string if there is no `-` in the string, change the line to:

```py
df['diagnosis'] = df['title'].apply(lambda x: x.split(' - ')[-1] if ' - ' in x else '')
```

Comment: I'm not sure if you would like to get the string even if there is no " - " in the cell though. I have edited the answer if you like

Answer (score 1):

Make a function which does the work of returning the value and then just apply it to that column.

```
import pandas as pd

s0 = '34 years old woman with pain in her XXX - Pharyngitis'
s1 = '67 years old man with xxx - yyy zzz - Nephropathy'
s2 = 'Metastatic Liver Cancer'

def f(x):
    return x.split(" - ")[-1]

df = pd.DataFrame([s0, s1, s2], columns=['title'])
df['diagnosis'] = df['title'].apply(f) 
print(df['diagnosis'])
```